# Where is the data constructor for 'State'?

Tags: haskell, monads

After reading a couple of tutorials on Haskell state monads I wanted to try them out myself. The tutorials I read claim that the Control.Monad.State provide the following definition:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }
```

However, I seem to be having trouble find the `State` data constructor:

```
Prelude> import Control.Monad.State
Prelude Control.Monad.State> :t State

<interactive>:1:1:
    Not in scope: data constructor `State'
    Perhaps you meant `StateT' (imported from Control.Monad.State)
```

I also tried a Hoogle search for `State` but did not find any data constructors with the expected type.

Where did the `State` constructor go? Did it ever exist? Or am I just looking in the wrong place? Essentially I would like to know what I need to do to create a state monad.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It doesn't exist any more. Unfortunately, this makes many Haskell resources on the web about it outdated.

To create a value, you can just use the [`state`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.0.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#v:state) function:

```
state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> State s a
```

`runState`, which used to be a field of `State`, is now just a normal function itself, but it works in the same way as before.

`State` has been rewritten in terms of the `StateT` monad transformer:

```
type State s = StateT s Identity
```

`StateT` itself has a constructor `StateT` that functions very similarly to the old `State` constructor:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a, s) }
```

The only difference is that there is an extra parameter `m`. This is just a slot where you can add in any other monad, which `StateT` then extends with state-handling capabilities. Naturally, to regain the old functionality of `State`, you just have to set `m` to `Identity`, which doesn't do anything.

```
newtype Identity a = Identity { runIdentity :: a }
```

Comment: This is quite similar to `Reader`, where the data constructor is not available. To create a value, use [`reader`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:reader) or [`asks`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:asks). For example `asks $ \x -> x - 1`.

Answer (score 20):

A while ago the [MTL](https://github.com/haskell/mtl) switched from

```
newtype State s a = State ...
```

to

```
type State s = StateT s Identity
```

since otherwise we had to duplicate the logic for every monad and its transformer. Instead you can now use the `state` function

```
state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> State s a
```

Sadly, [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/) and [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) both are out of date in this respect :(

Answer (score 8):

I am working through Learn You A Haskell (LYAH), and I thought that I would post the working version of the example code found at http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#state (Chapter 13, Section "Tasteful stateful computations")

The code that no longer works:

```
import Control.Monad.State  

pop :: State Stack Int  
pop = State $ \(x:xs) -> (x,xs)  

push :: Int -> State Stack ()  
push a = State $ \xs -> ((),a:xs)
```

The code modified to work:

```
import Control.Monad.State 

pop :: State Stack Int
-- note the change from "State" to "state"
pop = state $ \(x:xs) -> (x,xs)

push :: Int -> State Stack ()
push a = state $ \xs -> ((), a:xs)
```

The "stackManip" function works as is:

```
stackManip :: State Stack Int  
stackManip = do  
    push 3  
    a <- pop 
    pop
```